# MPAndroid how to show Y axis maximum always if value below a fixed value

Tags: android, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I am using MPAndroidChart to show a bargraph in my Android application. My Y axis values range is in between 0 and 30. I need to show Y axis labels from 0 to 5 always on viewport if Y axis values below 5. If exceeds 5, auto adjust the labels and show as usual. Any way to achieve this.